# How to generate and use Swift object method signature list?

Tags: swift

I realized that I could generate a list of methods:

```
class A {

    let methodList: [A -> Int -> Bool] = [methodA, methodB]

    func methodA(val: Int) -> Bool { return true }
    func methodB(val: Int) -> Bool { return false }

}
```

That's great. How do I create a loop that can call these methods? The obvious, like `obj.methodList[0](1)` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
let a = A()
let result = a.methodList[0](a)(1)
```

since your method probably needs an instance to resolve properly.